# Difference in these Linked List Pointer declarations

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

What is the difference between

1. `struct LinkedList *current = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));`

and

2. `struct LinkedList *current;`

where

```
struct LinkedList{
int data;
struct LinkedList *next;
}
```

When I was creating a LinkedList I couldn't achieve most of my desired outcomes with the latter LinkedList declaration.

Comment: What's the difference between `int x;` and `int x = 5;`? Same thing. One declaration has an initializer and one doesn't. But in your case, it's a pointer. Maybe read a tutorial that explains why you can't try to access (dereference) an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `dsa`? The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, in the student world DSA stands for data structures and algorithms

Comment: Well, for stackoverflow it is "Digital Signature Algorithm".  The tag even specifically states to **not** use it for "Data Structures and Algorithms".  As far as "student world", this is a recent phenomena (and in only certain parts of the world) where "DSA" is used to mean "Data Structures and Algorithms".  When I went to school, it was "Data Structures" and "Algorithmic Analysis", all spelled out, no abbreviations.

Comment: @TomKarzes This is incorrect analogy. In your example the memory is allocated for both cases.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The analogy is correct. In one case it's a pointer and in the other it isn't.  In my example, `x` is allocated in both cases.  In OP's example, `LinkedList` is allocated in both cases.  It's a perfect analogy.  The only difference is that I simplified the example by not using pointers, which makes it crystal clear.  The fact that the pointer intiializer happens to allocate memory has nothing to do with the analogy.  You're confusing the memory for the pointer variable with the memory it points to.

Comment: @TomKarzes The entire purpose of a pointer is to enable accessing and using the memory it references. You do not allocate a pointer for the sake of allocation and manipulation of it as data. So yes, the *pointer* memory is there in both cases (8 bytes or whatever) but this is definitely not what the question is about.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Did you not notice that this *wasn't* an answer, but merely a comment?  The point I was making, which my non-pointer example illustrated very clearly, was that the only difference between the two declarations was that one of them effectively included an assignment that initialized the variable, and the other did not.  I also mentioned that trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer won't work.  That was the sole point of the comment.  Criticizing it because it isn't a complete answer isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Well ig DSA is for Data Structures & Algorithms and I thought pointers are basic part of it

Comment: @DataScientisttobe -- Read the tag info before you apply it:  *DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) is a public-key signature algorithm defined by NIST. Do NOT use this tag for general "Data Structures and Algorithms" questions.*.   That info shows up on every tag that's applied.  Note that there are persons subscribed to `dsa` that are expecting questions based on the public key algorithm -- any questions on data structures with that tag will amount to spam.

Answer (score 3):

`struct LinkedList *current;` defines an object named `current` of type `struct LinkedList *` and does not specify an initial value for it. If it appears outside a function, the object is initialized to a null pointer. if it appears inside a function, it is not initialized, and the object’s value is indeterminate.

`struct LinkedList *current = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));` defines an object named `current` as above, calls `malloc` to allocate enough memory for an object of type `struct LinkedList`, and initializes `current` with the return value of `malloc`. This would normally appear inside a function, so that `malloc` is executed during program execution.

> When I was creating a LinkedList I couldn't achieve most of my desired outcomes with the 2nd mentioned code.

That is because `current` was not pointing to reserved memory, so attempting to use it as a pointer did something bad.

Comment: ohkayy, I see when using malloc it initializes it with a memory block of the specified size. Thanks mate

Comment: @DataScientisttobe To be more precise: Your `current` pointer is initialised with the address of the allocated memory.

Comment: Note: You still need to test `current` for `NULL`, the malloc may fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a pointer, it doesn't have an address. But if you equal it with `malloc` it has an address in memory with that size, and you can fill that addresses with some data.
If you use it without `malloc` and fill it in, you will get segmentation error in run time.

Run this code to see the result:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct LinkedList{
    int data;
    struct LinkedList *next;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    
    struct LinkedList *current = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
    current->data = 1;
    printf("%d\n", current->data );

    struct LinkedList *current1;
    current1->data = 2;
    printf("%d\n", current1->data );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between
> `struct LinkedList *current = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));` and `struct LinkedList *current;` ?

The difference is that int the first case `LinkedList` pointer is initialized and in the second it is not.

Note that in `C` you declare a variable giving the name and the type. So in

```
    struct LinkedList *current = NULL
```

you are declaring `current` as being of type `struct LinkedList*`

For the compiler spaces are irrevelant in this line.

If `current` is a pointer **then** `*current` is an instance of such type, `*current` is `struct LinkedList`. This is called de-referencing of a pointer, and this is `C`. But you are not declaring `*current`.

Writing the way you did can be misleading to beginners, by mixing cause and consequence. This is the real thing:

```
    struct LinkedList*                       current = NULL;
```

Then you see what `current` is being declared to be.

#### about `LinkedList`

```
        struct LinkedList
        {
            int                data;
            struct LinkedList* next;
        }
```

You can for sure name it `LinkedList` and write a correct program around that, with an actual linked list. But it is not an abstraction for a linked list. It seems to be just a *node* of a possible linked list of `int`.

A linked list is a collection of nodes. Possibly empty. And it has nothing to do with data. Each node by its turn contains or points to an unit of data, usually said to be a record.

If your description does not show that your code will be more complicated, less useful and harder to test. You will need loose pointers to beginning of lis, counters for size, sometimes pointers to the tail and so on.

### a complete example: a linked list of strings

Here follows a complete example using a list of strings, so you can see one way of writing and using a more generic list with some useful operations. And one that can be used on an on

#### output

```
    list created

3 elements back-inserted
    #2 elements in list.
    head element: Element 000001
    tail element: Element 000002
    "Element 000001" [15]
    "Element 000002" [15]

[-----]


3 elements inserted at front
    #4 elements in list.
    head element: Element 000004
    tail element: Element 000002
    "Element 000004" [15]
    "Element 000003" [15]
    "Element 000001" [15]
    "Element 000002" [15]

[-----]


after multi insert
    #18 elements in list.
    head element: Element 000004
    tail element: Overflow
    "Element 000004" [15]
    "Element 000003" [15]
    "Element 000001" [15]
    "Element 000002" [15]
    "7" [1]
    "8" [1]
    "9" [1]
    "10" [2]
    "11" [2]
    "12" [2]
    "A" [1]
    "list" [4]
    "has" [3]
    "nodes." [6]
    "Not" [3]
    "data" [4]
    "Stack" [5]
    "Overflow" [8]

[-----]

    list deleted
```

#### `main()` for this example

```
int main(void)
{   // now test the multi insert
    const char delim   = ' ';
    Info* temp    = NULL;
    List* my_list = so_create_list();  // a new list
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1)
    {
        temp = so_factory_info();
        so_insert_back(temp, my_list);
        free(temp);
    }
    so_print_list(my_list, "\n3 elements back-inserted\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1)
    {
        temp = so_factory_info();
        so_insert_front(temp, my_list);
        free(temp);
    }
    so_print_list(
        my_list, "\n3 elements inserted at front\n");
    so_multi_insert(
        my_list, delim, 3,
        "7  8   9   10   11 12", "A list has nodes. Not data", "Stack Overflow");
    so_print_list(my_list, "\nafter multi insert\n");
    so_delete_list(my_list);
    return 0;
}
```

#### The `List` is a list

```
    typedef struct
    {
        size_t size;
        Node*  tail;
        Node*  head;
    } List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes
```

This is a list. A list of nodes. Each `List` has its `size`, `head` and `tail`. *metadata* is the name of these things. So when you declare

```
        List list_set[42];
```

You are declaring an array of 42 lists. Each one has its size, head and tail. This is called *encapsulation* and makes life easier.

#### a node in `List`

```
        typedef struct st_node
        {
            struct st_node* prev;  // links
            struct st_node* next;

            Info* info;  // data
        } Node;
```

Each node is a link. We are building a linked lis after all. But each node has a pointer to some `Info` thing. Generic. So it can be reused.

#### data in the list

This is the data for the example, a mixed `C/Pascal` string.

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t length;
    char*  string;
} Thing;

typedef Thing Info;
```

What is `Thing` is not important. Note here the **key** `typedef` relating our present `List` content with `Info`: this is the way to reuse the `List` code. The list is always of nodes of `Info`. We just redefine `Info` each time.

### `List` and `Info` operations

- the `Info` thing can have pointers inside.
- we can try to insert dynamic allocated things into the list. If we free them the list will get corrupted and the program will crash.

So the list must *own* all is data. If we want the list to work for generic content nodes we need to know to copy a node, how to delete a note, and maybe how to display one n-screen, at least for testing.

We do not need to know how to **create** one, since when one uses a list of *something* it sure must have or know how to create *something*. A list if a list of existing things.

#### list operations

```
List* so_create_list();
List* so_delete_list(List*);
int   so_insert_back(Info*, List*);
int   so_insert_front(Info*, List*);
int   so_print_list(List*, const char* msg);
```

This is just an example, so only these operations are implemented. See that there is no mention of `Node` here. And the operations are defined in simple terms: only pointers. o insert data in a list we take a pointer to the data and a pointer to the list. The print operation accepts a title, useful in testing. See the code above.

These 2 helper functions

```
    int so_line_insert(
        const char* string, const char delim, List* list);
    int so_multi_insert(
        List* list, const char delim, const unsigned N, ...);
```

are useful for inserting words by line or by group into a list.

#### data operations

```
    Info* so_copy_info(const Info*);
    Info* so_delete_info(Info*);
    Info* so_factory_info();
    int   so_print_info(Info*, const char* msg);
```

- `so_factory_info` is here just for generating data for testing. It returns strings like "Element NNNNNN" so we can test for a few records or for thousands of them. From the example:

```
  Info* temp    = NULL;
  List* my_list = so_create_list();  // a new list
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1)
  {
      temp = so_factory_info();
      so_insert_back(temp, my_list);
      free(temp);
  }
  so_print_list(my_list, "\n3 elements back-inserted\n");
```

prints

```
    list created

3 elements back-inserted
    #2 elements in list.
    head element: Element 000001
    tail element: Element 000002
    "Element 000001" [15]
    "Element 000002" [15]

[-----]
```

#### complete code

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// info, node and list

typedef struct
{
    size_t length;
    char*  string;
} Thing;

typedef Thing Info;

Info* so_copy_info(const Info*);
Info* so_delete_info(Info*);
Info* so_factory_info();
int   so_print_info(Info*, const char* msg);

typedef struct st_node
{
    struct st_node* prev;  // links
    struct st_node* next;

    Info* info;  // data
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    Node*  tail;
    Node*  head;
} List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes

List* so_create_list();
List* so_delete_list(List*);
int   so_insert_back(Info*, List*);
int   so_insert_front(Info*, List*);
int   so_print_list(List*, const char* msg);

//
// helpers to build a list
//

int so_line_insert(
    const char* string, const char delim, List* list);
int so_multi_insert(
    List* list, const char delim, const unsigned N, ...);

int main(void)
{   // now test the multi insert
    const char delim   = ' ';
    Info* temp    = NULL;
    List* my_list = so_create_list();  // a new list
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1)
    {
        temp = so_factory_info();
        so_insert_back(temp, my_list);
        free(temp);
    }
    so_print_list(my_list, "\n3 elements back-inserted\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1)
    {
        temp = so_factory_info();
        so_insert_front(temp, my_list);
        free(temp);
    }
    so_print_list(
        my_list, "\n3 elements inserted at front\n");
    so_multi_insert(
        my_list, delim, 3,
        "7  8   9   10   11 12", "A list has nodes. Not data", "Stack Overflow");
    so_print_list(my_list, "\nafter multi insert\n");
    so_delete_list(my_list);
    return 0;
}

//
// helper functions:
//

#define ST_OUT 0
#define ST_IN 1
#define MAX_SIZE 255

//
// insert string into list, word by word
//

int so_line_insert(
    const char* string, const char delim, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;

    char state                = ST_OUT;
    char a_word[1 + MAX_SIZE] = {0};  // buffer for word
    Info data   = {.length = 0, .string = (char*)&a_word};
    data.length = 0;
    Info* temp  = NULL;
    // break string into words and put on list
    const char* p_in  = string;
    char*       p_out = data.string;
    while (*p_in != 0)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case ST_OUT:  // out of word
                if (*p_in == delim)
                {  // not in word
                    ++p_in;
                }
                else
                {  // new word starting here
                    p_out       = data.string;
                    *p_out      = *p_in;
                    state       = ST_IN;
                    data.length = 1;
                    ++p_in;
                    ++p_out;
                }
                break;
            case ST_IN:  // in a word
            default:     // in a word
                if (*p_in == delim)
                {                // end of word
                    *p_out = 0;  // end string
                    temp   = so_copy_info(&data);
                    so_insert_back(temp, list);
                    free(temp);
                    state =
                        ST_OUT;  // in search for another
                    ++p_in;
                }
                else
                {  // just another letter
                    *p_out = *p_in;
                    data.length += 1;
                    ++p_in;
                    ++p_out;
                }
                break;
        };  // switch(state)
    };      // while()
    // now *p_in == 0, end of line
    if (state == ST_OUT) return 0;
    // state was ST_IN and reached end of input
    if (p_out == data.string) return 0;  // was empty
    // inserts last word into list
    *p_out = 0;
    temp   = so_copy_info(&data);
    so_insert_back(temp, list);
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}

int so_multi_insert(
    List* list, const char delim, const unsigned N, ...)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        so_line_insert(va_arg(args, char*), delim, list);
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}


// list code 

// data related functions

Info* so_copy_info(const Info* orig)
{
    if (orig == NULL) return NULL;
    Info* cp = malloc(sizeof(Info));
    if (cp == NULL) return NULL;
    cp->string = malloc(1 + orig->length);
    if (cp->string == NULL)
    {
        free(cp);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(cp->string, orig->string);
    cp->length = orig->length;
    return cp;  // returns the address of the copy
}

Info* so_delete_info(Info* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;
    if (del->string != NULL) free(del->string);
    free(del);
    return NULL;
}

Info* so_factory_info()
{
    Info* one = malloc(sizeof(Info));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    static int len = 1;
    one->string    = malloc(30);
    one->length =
        1 + sprintf(one->string, "Element %06d", len);
    ++len;
    return one;
}

int so_print_info(Info* info, const char* msg)
{
    if (info == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "    \"%s\" [%llu]\n", info->string, info->length);
    return 0;
}

// list related functions

List* so_create_list()
{
    List* list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "    list created\n");
    return list;
}

List* so_delete_list(List* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;  // no list
    for (size_t i = 0; i < del->size; i += 1)
    {  // delete nodes, 1 by 1
        Node* save = del->head->next;
        so_delete_info(del->head->info);
        free(del->head);
        del->head = save;
    };
    free(del);  // delete list
    fprintf(stderr, "    list deleted\n");
    return NULL;
}

// inserts 'info' at the tail of the list
int so_insert_back(Info* info, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->info = so_copy_info(info);
    if (list->size == 0)  // first node
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->next       = NULL;
    list->tail->next = node;
    list->tail       = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

// inserts 'info' at the head of the list
int so_insert_front(Info* info, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->info = so_copy_info(info);
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->next = list->head;
    list->head = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

int so_print_list(List* list, const char* msg)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("No valid list!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "\
    #%llu elements in list.\n\
    head element: %s\n\
    tail element: %s\n",
        list->size, list->head->info->string,
        list->tail->info->string);
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        so_print_info(p->info, NULL);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n[-----]\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```